# No wireless toggle. All drivers are installed, but there is no wifi

Tags: settings, wifi, drivers, internet

I am noob about ubuntu. Yesterday I installed the latest version of elementary os. my laptop is dell inspiron 5591-2n1. Wifi is intel wireless ac 9560. There is no wifi option. I can't turn it on/off. no available wifi's. It seems like there are no drivers installed but I'm pretty sure all drivers are installed. What can I do?

Comment: please paste a screen shot of your window so i can justify your conclusion

Comment: Which window should I screen shot

Comment: the main window, just click ctrl + printscreen

Comment: https://imgur.com/FLcOtDY

Comment: i can see an internet, this is lan or usb tethering? please click on the internet icon to see the options

Comment: It's usb tethering... There is no wireless option

Comment: i just wanted to see it in the picture,
type in the terminal `ifconfig` and show me the output

Comment: https://imgur.com/hKj5z8I

Comment: assuming this is the entire picture, the wifi is not listed, try this command `lspci`

Comment: https://imgur.com/NV10K2y

Comment: write this in terminal  
`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

if still nothing happened, write this

`sudo apt install software-properties-common`

then type software updates in the application search and open additional drivers and try to update things around

Comment: E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: please paste a screen shot

Comment: https://imgur.com/4DlKGTR

Comment: when you where first installing elementary, when there was an option saying "install 3rd party software to install drivers" did you select it?

Comment: Yes, I did.....

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141671/cant-update-securely-and-is-therefore-disabled

Comment: after doing these steps, try to update and upgrade and update me

Comment: done, but still no updates and nothing changes

Comment: so install gnome software updates as mentioned previously, and show me the window

Comment: sorry. there is something wrong. It can't update

Comment: https://imgur.com/l0S0Gp0

Comment: i'm 100% sure that you messed up with the debian sources list, please paste a screen shot of software updates if you installed it + a picture of this command
`sudo nano -c //etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: https://imgur.com/P4n63W2

Comment: + I haven't installed anything

Comment: 1. recomment the elementary os source
2.scroll down to show me all the sources

Comment: btw, just comment those 2 sources you added (the one  that cause the error, in order not to complicate things, these will not help right now and are causing an issue. and briefly, apt searches those links for whatever you apply for them for example if you search for spotify, those are the sources that apt will search for. (just explaining things around)

Comment: I don't know what I've done! Probably need to reinstall the elementary os and that will fix the sources problem. But the wifi problem will sure stay, because tried reinstalling it. never worked

Comment: do you have any other account so we can chat there?

Comment: no problem, i want to also figure out where is the issue, if you still have the usb you installed elementary with it, try boothing from it and press "try elementary" rather than installing and tell me if you have wifi working

Comment: no wifi in "try elementary"

Comment: it's same.. I only have internet with usb tethering

Comment: generally, if it is the same i would recommend installing the wireless card manually, just go to intel and pickup your card and install through `sudo dpkg -i nameOfPackage.deb`

google search-> pasteHereNameOf card "linux" site:intel.com

Comment: okay. I reinstalled the system. I've found my intel driver, but it's ucode file

Comment: what you mean by ucode, could you print screen?

Comment: here what it shows when I'm trying to update
https://imgur.com/Egxbe7Y

Comment: and here is my driver file
https://imgur.com/TyKp2zI

Comment: ok, to make things much faster, you want discord or something?

Comment: https://discord.gg/MA48j7